# SWF virtual magizine effet for smart devices

Tags: php, android, flash, swfobject, adobe-indesign

I'm working on a novel that I write in Adobes InDesign and saves down and export to a swf file that genrates a page turning effect with some bookmarks jumping, and upload it to my webbsite. The proble is that the script only works while on a computer and not while on a smart devices. I've tried to download a bunch of different SWF and flas playing aps but can't find any that works, the page remains wite and empty. Is there some setting you can use or a app that ave been vonfirmed being able to display the virtual magazine function of SWF-files?

Comment: SWF in a browser needs the Flash Plugin and there is no Flash Plugin for mobile web browsers. To run SWF with code (ActionScript 3) you have to use Flash CC (now called Adobe Animate) to make an Android App (of your novel) to be installed. Otherwise I suggest if you want it viewed on a mobile browser can you not just make a link to a "mobile version" (HTML5) which just shows images without effect? There are HTML5 transition effects examples for images out there on google if you really want some effect on mobile viewing.